# Reverse a set of points in c++

Tags: c++, math

I need to generate points around a quarter circle in the anticlockwise direction but with my program I'm able to generate in clockwise direction. Below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int NumberPoints(10);
    double x1;
    const double PI = 3.14159;
    double radius = 5;
    double angle = 0.7853; //45 degrees

    ofstream plot;
    string plotDataFile("points.txt");
    plot.open(plotDataFile.c_str());

    for (int i = 0; i <= NumberPoints; i++)
    {
        x1 = angle/NumberPoints*i;
        plot << setprecision(5) << radius * sin(x1) << " ";
        plot << setprecision(5) << radius * cos(x1) << " " << endl;
    }
    plot.close();
}
```

I get the following output.

```
0 5 
0.39225 4.9846 
0.78208 4.9385 
1.1671 4.8619 
1.5449 4.7553 
1.9132 4.6195 
2.2697 4.4552 
2.6122 4.2634 
2.9386 4.0453 
3.2469 3.8023 
3.5352 3.5359
```

I need points in the format
    3.5352 3.5359 
    3.2469 3.8023 
    2.9386 4.0453 
    .
    .
    0 5
Could someone help me modify my code or give me an idea for the same.

Comment: There is a [std::reverse()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) function.

Comment: Did you try `x1 = -angle/NumberPoints*i;` already?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, i tried. it enters the second quadrant.

Comment: `x1 = angle/NumberPoints*(NumberPoints-i);`

Answer (score 0):

just iterate backwards:

```
for (int i = NumberPoints; i >= 0; i--)
```

By the way, your variable NumberPoints has probably wrong name. Notice that you are getting 11 points, not 10.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
for (int i = NumberPoints; i >= 0; i--)
{
    x1 = angle/NumberPoints*i;
    plot << setprecision(5) << radius * sin(x1) << " ";
    plot << setprecision(5) << radius * cos(x1) << " " << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i <= NumberPoints; i++)
```

use

```
for (int i = NumberPoints; i >= 0; i--)
```

Comment: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition, accept the best answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

**may be help**

**Input**:

```
0 5 
0.39225 4.9846 
0.78208 4.9385
```

---

```
std::vector< std::pair< std::string, std::string > > pair_of_point;
pair_of_point.emplace_back("0", "5");
pair_of_point.emplace_back("0.39225", "4.9846");
pair_of_point.emplace_back("0.78208", "4.9385");

std::reverse( pair_of_point.begin(), pair_of_point.end()) ;

std::cout << pair_of_point[ 0 ].first << " " << pair_of_point[ 0 ].second << std::endl;
std::cout << pair_of_point[ 1 ].first << " " << pair_of_point[ 1 ].second << std::endl;
std::cout << pair_of_point[ 2 ].first << " " << pair_of_point[ 2 ].second << std::endl;
```

---

**output**

```
0.78208 4.9385
0.39225 4.9846
0 5
```

Instead of **std::string** enter you date-type